# Посчитать количество элементов в jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Мне нужно считать количество блоков в блоке с классом .blocks и в зависимости от их количества, создать столько же ссылок на эти элементы. Каждая ссылка будет скролить к соответствующему элементу.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно это реализовать? Буду очень благодарен.

```html
<div class="blocks">
  <div class="section">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    3
  </div>
</div>

<ul class="navigation">
<li><a href="">Блок 1</a></li>
<li><a href="">Блок 2</a></li>
<li><a href="">Блок 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: $('.blocks').children().length;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
$('.blocks .section').each(function(index, element){
  $(this).attr('data-block', index);  
  $('.navigation').append('<li class="scrollto" data-block="'+index+'">Блок '+$(element).html()+'</li>')
});

$(document).on('click', '.navigation .scrollto', function(){
  var block_id = $(this).attr('data-block'),
      block = $('[data-block="'+block_id+'"]:not(.scrollto)');
  if (block.offset() !== undefined){
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: block.offset().top
    }, 1000, 'swing', function(){
      // здесь код если надо что-то делать после прокрутки
    });
  }
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blocks">
  <div class="section">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    3
  </div>
</div>

<ul class="navigation">
</ul>
```

В данном случае не обязательно подсчитывать. Достаточно просто для каждого блока вставлять ссылку, т.е.

```
$('.blocks .section').each(function(index, element){
    $('.navigation').append('<li><a href="">Блок '+$(element).html()+'</a></li>')
});
```

Comment: Ваш код почему-то не работает :(

Comment: Ну, расчет был на то что вы сможете если что увидеть ошибку в консоли и понять что не так - т.к. код писался просто из головы, без проверки. Но, на всякий случай - поправил.

Comment: Супер! Спасибо! А скажите пожалуйста ещё, как сделать в Вашем случае анимацию скрола? Не пойму, куда указывать интервал задержки..

Comment: Тут вам уже необходимо написать событие на нажатие ссылки. При нажатии должна применяться функция animate() - пример я добавлю в правке к ответу.

Comment: Все, пример кода теперь со скролом. Посмотреть в работе - можно тут https://jsfiddle.net/42L7m2gy/

Comment: Спасибо большое! Отметил решение как верное. А ещё не подскажите, как вешать на активный блок класс и отслеживать, если я сейчас проскролил на 2 блок, то второй точке добавляю класс, а с других удаляю. Или отдельный вопрос нужно создать?

Comment: Лучше другой, т.к. это уже другая тематика

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709163/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0 создал вопрос здесь, посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Если ссылки для скролла, наверное стоит все же делать это через id. Как добавить ссылки уже скинули (хотя не думаю, что секции действительно будут содержать цифры от чего пример нельзя назвать удачным), но на всякий случай скину ещё такой вариант.

```js
$(function() {
  scrollToSection();
});

function scrollToSection() {
  let $blocks = $('.blocks'),
    $sections = $blocks.find('.section'),
    $navigation = $('.navigation');
    
  createAnchor();
    
  function createAnchor() {
    for(let i = 1; i <= $sections.length; i++) {
      let id = `section_${i}`;
      
      $sections.eq(i).attr('id', id)
      $navigation.append(`<li><a href="#${id}">Блок ${i}</a></li>`);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blocks">
  <div class="section">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    3
  </div>
</div>

<ul class="navigation"></ul>
```